# How to change height of UITextView from xib programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITextView with non-editable text inside of it that I have made in a xib, and I need it to automatically change its height (when it's displayed), so that it perfectly fits the text inside of it. I have tried numerous methods but the majority either don't work on ios7 or just dont seem to work for me. I figured it might just be a problem with what I'm seeing. Here's the code that I'm running:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,5,5);
storyText.frame = frame;
NSLog(@"%f", storyText.frame.size.height);
```

I have put this method both in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but it doesn't seem to work in either of them. The NSLog is indeed printing 5, but this is what i'm seeing when i run the app.

[image: textField]

What I am seeing above is exactly what it looks like in my xib. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your issue like that:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,5,5);
    storyText.frame = frame;
});
```